# Cannot find the Google Script library I have already created

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, shared-libraries

I finally got around to putting my script into a reusable library that I can share between other Google Sheets scripts.  I have the URL (it opens to just the signature of the library functions) and the deployment ID.

It is definitely connected and working with my Google Sheet script.

I have no idea where the source code is stored so I can edit it!  Believe me, I have Googled this.  There is discussion on how to add your library to your script, but I could not find anything about editing an existing library.

- I have searched my Google Drive.
- I have looked in my Google Docs.
- I have tried putting a break point in my script and stepping into the library function. (Note that [this article](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries#:%7E:text=When%20you%20have%20access%20to,read%2Dlevel%20access%20to%20it.) says stepping into the library function should work).

Bubkis!  Where is the darned code stored?!?!

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured this out.  When you initially create the library, you are in a script.  THIS is where the code is (I had assumed that a new library was created with this code.)